# C++ undeclared identifier with 2 classes in same header

Tags: c++11, debugging

Please help, I have these lines of code:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_ARMY_H
#define UNTITLED_ARMY_H

using namespace std;

#include <vector>

class Country {

public:

    vector <DiplomacyRequest> pendingDiplomacy;  //Line 12

    Country() {} } ;

class DiplomacyRequest {

    Country issuerCountry;

    int money = 0;

    void acceptRequest();
    void declainRequest();

public:
    DiplomacyRequest() {} };

#endif //UNTITLED_ARMY_H
```

and I've been provided with an error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'DiplomacyRequest', at line 12

Where is the fault?

Comment: You need to forward declare DiplomacyRequest. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to `DiplomacyRequest` in line 12 before declaring it. You can use a [*forward-declaration*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) to fix the issue, [as `std::vector` is guaranteed to work with incomplete types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html).

```
class DiplomacyRequest;

class Country
{

public:
    vector<DiplomacyRequest> pendingDiplomacy; // Line 12

    Country()
    {
    }
};

class DiplomacyRequest
{

    Country issuerCountry;

    int money = 0;

    void acceptRequest();
    void declainRequest();

public:
    DiplomacyRequest()
    {
    }
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZSfyf7Iqx2F9gxsu)